# FATAL: sorry, too many clients already , hikari pool maxsize exceeded

Tags: spring, hikaricp, max-pool-size

I am trying to configure my master & read-only data sources as below,

But when I start the application it opens 6 Hikari pools as shown in the log,

Do you have an opinion on why it is creating 6 pools already?

And also another situation occurs when I run my tests,

On my test configurations, I have two application.yml's which only differentiate from the DB value.

And when I start to run all my test suites and when it hits the test file using different db configuration it starts to get the following error.

SQL State  : 53300
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

How could I solve these two problems?

Thanks.

```
o.m.c.d.d.DataSourcesConfiguration       : Hit masterDataSource() data source
2023-02-20 10:23:05.930  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:05.939  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:06.025  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2023-02-20 10:23:06.034  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-20 10:23:06.034  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.c.d.d.DataSourcesConfiguration       : Hit readonlyDataSource() data source
2023-02-20 10:23:06.034  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:06.034  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-4 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:06.055  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-4 - Start completed.
2023-02-20 10:23:06.058  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Start completed.
2023-02-20 10:23:06.058  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.c.d.d.DataSourcesConfiguration       : Set default data source as master
2023-02-20 10:23:06.058  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] o.m.c.d.d.DataSourcesConfiguration       : Hit masterDataSource() data source
2023-02-20 10:23:06.058  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:06.058  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-6 - Starting...
2023-02-20 10:23:06.071  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-6 - Start completed.
2023-02-20 10:23:06.074  INFO 40442 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-5 - Start completed.
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataSourcesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

    private int minimumIdle = 0
    private int maximumPoolSize = 4
    private int keepaliveTime = 240000


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        RoutingDataSource masterSlaveRoutingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceType.MASTER, masterDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceType.READONLY, readonlyDataSource());
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        log.info("Set default data source as master");
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());
        return masterSlaveRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Qualifier("readonlyDataSource")
    public DataSource readonlyDataSource() {
        log.info("Hit readonlyDataSource() data source");
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceConfig.getReadonlyUrl());
        return connectionPoolDataSource(hikariDataSource);
    }

    @Primary
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(dataSourceConfig.getMasterUrl());
        return connectionPoolDataSource(hikariDataSource);
    }

    
    protected HikariConfig hikariConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSource);
        hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
        hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(keepaliveTime);
        return hikariConfig;
    }

    protected HikariDataSource connectionPoolDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig(dataSource));
    }

}
```

Comment: You need `@Bean`  on your readonly and master datasource as well. Each time you call that method, without `@Bean` it will create an instance. As you are creating a new one again in `connectionPoolDatasOURCE` (why?) each call actually generates 2 instances.  Your config is wrong and way to convoluted.

Comment: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence.git I have benefited from this repository which uses the same way, what do you prefer to fix it ?

Comment: The moment I add  @Bean definitions it never forwards to the read-only source for get operations, so cause the application works wrong? So this cause more major problem for me , what do you think about reason of this

Comment: Your configureation and setup. Removing the `@Bean` isn't the solution. You probably still hav open session in view enabled which will retrieve a connection very early, as your default is the master it will always open to that datasource. ALso the repo you link to has nothing that resembles what you are doing, if it was it was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong on multiple levels.

1. Your `readonlyDataSource` and `masterDataSource` are missing an `@Bean`
2. The `@Primary` should be on your `dataSource` (currently it doesn't do anything as it isn't on an `@Bean` method)
3. Each call to either `readonlyDataSource` or `masterDataSource` creates 2 instances of a datasource. As you have no `@Bean` and are calling `masterDataSource` 2 times, this results in 3 * 2 is 6 instances.

In short fix your configuration as it is way to convoluted.

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataSourcesConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

    private int minimumIdle = 0
    private int maximumPoolSize = 4
    private int keepaliveTime = 240000

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        RoutingDataSource masterSlaveRoutingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceType.MASTER, masterDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(DataSourceType.READONLY, readonlyDataSource());
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        log.info("Set default data source as master");
        masterSlaveRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource());
        return masterSlaveRoutingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource readonlyDataSource() {
        return configure(dataSourceConfig.getReadonlyUrl());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {
        return configure(dataSourceConfig.getMasterUrl());
    }

    
    private HikariDataSource configure(String url) {
        HikariDataSource datasource = new HikariDataSource();
        datasource.setJdbcUrl(url);
        datasource.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
        datasource.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
        datasource.setKeepaliveTime(keepaliveTime);
        return datasource;
    }
}
```

This will only create 2 instances in a much more readable way.

Another thing is, which people tend to forget, is that by default Spring Boot enables the open-entity-manager-in-view pattern. Which leads to obtaining a connection to the database very early in the process. As your `masterDataSource` is the default one it will always open one to that datasource.

You can disable it by setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false` in your `application.properties`.

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

**WARNING:** Be aware that this might (or rather will) affect other parts of your application that rely (unknowingly) on lazy loading. Those won't work anymore as the `EntityManager` will be closed right after the transaction commits/rollbacks.

Comment: Again (or rather still) your code/configuration. Your database runs out of connections. Your max size of connections is 4, if you are messing around with stuff yourself (or are abusing `@SpringBootTest`) things get awry pretty fast. However this question was about your 6 datasources which was related to your setup. Your remaining issue is for another question.